# About Node.js why I cannot get data from database while using same uri

Tags: node.js

Why I can't get the data from this database for second items. I create a collection for my second data but while I call API, it can't get in localhost.

```
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.ipeja.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
console.log(uri);
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

 async function run(){
       try{
            await client.connect();
            const productCollection = client.db('splabwarehouse').collection('products');
            const itemCollection = client.db('splabitemcategory').collection('itemcategory');
            
            app.get('/products',async(req,res)=>{

            const query ={};
            const cursor = productCollection.find(query);
            const products = await cursor.toArray();
            res.send(products);
            });

            app.get('/items',async(req,res)=>{

            const query ={};
            const cursor = itemCollection.find(query);
            const items = await cursor.toArray();
            res.send(items);
            });



       }
       finally{

       }
 }

 run().catch(console.dir)
```

Comment: You might want to remove that `try` block which is swallowing all errors. Like that, everything that could possiblygo wrong will fail silently.

Comment: @m90 Better advice is to add `.catch()` block in order to catch the errors.